# ActivityNotFoundException while intent to Another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am Coding In Kotlin
I have Tried To Intent To Activity From My Another Activity(Not MainActivity)
When I run my app on mobile it Throw Me error .

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctij6.jpg)

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

but I had declared the activity in Manifest

Manifest Code For Those Activitys :

```
   <activity android:name=".Register_user_soma" />

 <activity
        android:name=".AccountManager"
         />
```

Intent Code From Register_user_soma :

```
 val AccountManager:TextView = findViewById(R.id.AccountManager)

    AccountManager.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this, AccountManager::class.java))

     }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong And I know many question is Like This But Answer is not works For Me

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please share complete code of AccountManager and MainActivity  code.

Comment: I Solved This By Changing Variable Name Because The variable name and intent class must not be same